# Automapper MapExpression - No coercion operator is defined

Tags: automapper

I'm having difficulties creating a new ObjectMapper for Automapper (7.0.1)
I'm trying to create an Object mapper that take a source value and assign it to an object property so I can create a map between an int to a specific type of object.

So here is my MapExpression

```
public Expression MapExpression(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, ProfileMap profileMap, 
    PropertyMap propertyMap, Expression sourceExpression, Expression destExpression, Expression contextExpression)
{
    var property = Property(destExpression, "Value");

    return Assign(property, Convert(sourceExpression, property.Type));
}
```

sourceExpression DebugView

> $resolvedValue

destExpression DebugView

> .If ($dest == null) {
>       .Default(Prextra.Domain.SelectLists.SYS.StateSelectListItem) } .Else {
>       $typeMapDestination.State }

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I get this exception, so I guess it tries to assign the Int32 value to the object instead of the property?

> InvalidOperationException: No coercion operator is defined between
>   types 'System.Int32' and
>   'Prextra.Domain.SelectLists.SYS.StateSelectListItem'

Comment: You can try [a simple object mapper first](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/dbffa1d11d67d044bbfbf35ceb72cf2296821b47/src/UnitTests/Mappers/CustomMapperTests.cs#L92) and then try to optimize using expressions afterwards.

Comment: As I understand, I need to know the destination type while using a simple ObjectMapper, I couldn't use ObejctMapper<int, IMyType<>>

Comment: You can use object, but maybe for your case a generic map would also work.

Comment: I got it to work using simple objectMapper<,>, but I'd really like to understand what I was doing wrong using Expressions

Comment: Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).